# How to test if std::ifstream reached EOL

Tags: c++11, ifstream

I have an std::ifstream of a file containing space separated values on multiple lines.

Is there anyway to know if there I reached the end of a line when reading from the std::ifstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get to guess how you are currently reading it

No,

```
 ins >> stuff;
```

discards whitespace.

You want to do a

```
std::getline(ins, line_string);
```

And process it line by line.